# Is there always a matrix $X$ such that $X^2=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Is it true that for every $A\in M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb{C})$ there's an $X\in M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb{C})$ such that $X^2=A$?

For the matter of fact, I don't have a clue, other than evaluating the general case and solve the system of equations.

I also thought about the fact that we're aobve $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore the characteristic polynomial can be factored to linear terms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Note that $A^2 = 0$. Thus, if $B^2 = A$, then $B^4 = 0$. But since $B$ is a 2 by 2 matrix, if $B^4 = 0$, then $B^2 = 0$. Therefore $A$ has no "square root."

Answer (score 8):

No: the matrix $E=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is such that $E^2=0$. If there were a matrix $X$ such that $X^2=E$, it would be nilpotent. However, by Hamilton-Cayley, the index of nilpotency (the smallest $k$ such that $X^k=0$) is at most $2$ in a space of dimension $2$, so that we would have $X^2=0=E$.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not true but such a matrix exists if $A$ is hermitian. You can show this by diagonalization.

Answer (score 2):

You can show that there is no matrix $X = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)$ such that $X^2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right)$.